# I have a strange mistake

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I have a problem with a script: I want to put it on an object but I have an error

can't add script component 'enemie AI' because the script class cannot be found.Make sure that there are no compile errors and that the file name and class name match.

Comment: I think you should change the question title into: "I cannot assign a MonoBehaviour to a GameObject in the editor".

Answer (score 3):

### Space is not valid in the class name

If you class has a space it cannot be used so this name is invalid.
"enemie AI"

### Class Name and File Name must be equal

Make sure that also the name of your monobehviour script is the same of the class.

=> enemyAI name of the class class
=> enemyAI.cs name of the file

IF they are different you won't be able to place it on the gameobject.

[image]

They are also case sensitive.
So enemyAi is not the same as enemyAI.